# Xml shoutcast to a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, xml

i have made a php file to retrieve data to a database from a xml file and it works:

```
$title = $xml->SONGTITLE; {


// performing sql query

$sql = "INSERT INTO test_xml (`title`) VALUES ('$title') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE time = now()";
```

the xml is from a shoutcast server, witch is made automatically from my radio. 
The xml line is:

```
<SONGTITLE>Morrissey - Don`t Make Fun of Daddy`s Voice (John Peel session)</SONGTITLE>
```

is there a way to separate the artist from the Song name?
And retrieve title to title and artist to artist.
Can you give me ideas how to start?

Comment: seems that " - " is the separator, you might want to look into `explode()`

Comment: Thank you @michi it worked good, see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anwser is:

```
$title = $xml->SONGTITLE; {
$pieces = explode("-", $title);
```

// performing sql query

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test_xml (`title`, `artist`) VALUES ('$pieces[1]',   '$pieces[0]') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE time = now()";
```